# C# Get URL path from local directory

Tags: c#, url, path, directory, virtual

Here is my program:
I'm uploading an image(Stream, FileInfo or whatever you like) to a server at this virtual directory: "C:\_Resources\Assets"

But then, I want the server to return the URL path of that image to display it in an  tag, that is to say "http://localhost/Trunk/Assets/image.jpeg"

In fact, I'm trying to do the opposite of the Server.MapPath Method.

How do I get that please?

Thanks.

Comment: The solution to your problem is going to be very server specific - the correct way to achieve this for Apache is going to be different for IIS, and both of those will differ from plain Windows file shares.

If you want some help, please give the rest of us enough information to help you! Thanks.

Comment: Do you want a UNC (`\\server\share\path\file`)? Or a URL (`http://server/path/file`)?

Answer (score 2):

url = "\\" + Environment.MachineName + Path.GetFullPath(document.FileName).ToString().Split(':')[1];

Comment: This doesn't account for share name in the event of being used remotely

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a string and replace the "C:_Resources" with "/Trunk" ?
Might not be ideal but it should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

```
string file = "\\\\" + someServer + "\\" + someFile;
file = file.Replace(":\\","$\\");
```

And, if you don't feel like using those sill escape characters...

```
string file = @"\\" + someServer + @"\" + someFile;
file = file.Replace(@":\",@"$\");
```